# WPF Button Style based on another Style with Animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, styling

I'm currently learning WPF Animations.

Currently I have this Button style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultFont}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource MinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource C4}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="{DynamicResource Radius}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="borderBackground" Color="{StaticResource Col5}" />
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Black" />
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="beginStoryboard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="borderBackground"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    To="{StaticResource Col2}"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                    </ColorAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="beginStoryboard" />
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="e">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="borderBackground"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    To="{StaticResource Col5}"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                    </ColorAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{DynamicResource Radius}" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

As you can see, this style should do a few things:

- Apply a default `FontFamily`, `MinHeight` and `Background`;
- Animate mouse enter and mouse leave effect with a `ColorAnimation`. Colors are defined as Resources with names like Col1, Col2, etc.

Everything is working properly (even if I suspect this Style could be rewritten in a more coincise way, but I need to be pointed in the right direction).

My issue is: I need to create another Style based on this main Style, so I wrote something like:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="AccentOnMouseOver" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately this does not work (the base style is applied but no `BorderBrush` color).
How can I write a base style with Background `ColorAnimation` and then derive from it with another style, adding other `Triggers`?

A solution would be to just copy and paste the entire base style, adding a x:Key and editing the propererties I need, but I'd like something cleaner (so that if I change the animation part it is applied to all derived styles).

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: You can override a property with another setter or you could define resources. Brush and width could be given default values resources defined in a resource dictionary you merge in app. You could set different values in some style replaced resources of the button or ( I think probably )  in your inherited style setting the controltemlate resources. Or you could bind to attached dependency properties, give those values in your main style. Set specific values on buttons you want to be different.

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake is an incorrect understanding of the logic of the element template and its interaction with the style.

1. In your example, the main Border displays the border, but it has a “hard” specified value: `<Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="0"`. At a minimum, you need to change this to `<Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"`.
2. The color of the border for the "MouseOver" state is set in the Template trigger:

```xml
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Black" />
```

Therefore, in this state, the binding to the parent element property will no longer work (its priority is lower than that of the template trigger setter): `<Border x:Name="Border" ... BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">`. Therefore, for this state, setting a value to a property of the parent element does not make sense.

You cannot set more than one value for one property AT A TIME. Therefore, you should come up with some kind of mechanism for disabling the trigger in the Template if you need to trigger a change in the same property later, at the place where the element is used.

**Solutions.**
In any case, you will have to create your own completely new template, since the logic of this template does not allow you to work with the element as you need.
When creating a template, first of all, you need to immediately decide which elements, parameters, and values you will have constant and which you will need to configure later at the place where the element is used.
Custom parameters (if they are not properties of the parent element) are set in two main ways: dynamic resource keys (DynamicResource) or AttachedProperty (example - Material Design package).